# Where is the post where the original Bitcoin Whitepaper was first released?

Tags: satoshi-nakamoto

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When and how did Bitcoin start?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/659/when-and-how-did-bitcoin-start)

I understand Satoshi release the original whitepaper to some cryptography mailing list, in 2009 I believe. Can anyone point me to that thread?

It would be interesting to see the first responses the whitepaper received.

Comment: That's covered in this question: [When and how did Bitcoin start?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/659/when-and-how-did-bitcoin-start) so I'll close this one. The link is in the accepted answer.

Comment: @D.H. - actually, the correct link wasn't in the accepted answer, but I managed to find it nonetheless via by digging from there - updated the accepted answer with the link.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that, I confused the announcement of the design paper with the announcement of the first release. Thanks for updating the answer.